# ThunkAction getting returned by dispatch instead of the Return Type of the ThunkAction

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

How can I configure Typescript to work with react-redux and redux-thunk so that `dispatch` returns the return type of the ThunkAction getting dispatched instead of a `ThunkAction<a,b,c,d,e>`?

```js
export function addPerson(
  person: Person
): PersonActionTypes {
  return {
    type: ADD_PERSON,
    person,
  }
}


export const savePerson = (
  person: Person
): ThunkAction<
  Promise<Person>,
  RootState,
  unknown,
  Action<string>
> => async (dispatch): Promise<Person> => {
  const savedPerson = await PersonApi.save(person)
  dispatch(addPerson(savedPerson))
  return savedPerson
}
```

When I dispatch this action, I would like for it return a `Promise<Person>` but dispatch returns `ThunkAction<Promise<void>, RootState, unknown, Action<string>>`

```js
const savedPerson = await dispatch(savePerson(person))
// savedPerson is a ThunkAction as far as TypeScript is concerned but I would like it to be a Person.
```

Comment: What if you do `const savedPerson = await savePerson(person)(dispatch)`

Answer (score 3):

Faced the same problem. After some time found a solution which worked for me.
The problem here is that `dispatch` by default gets type `Dispatch` and it is ok for simple actions, but is not for `ThunkAction`.

My thunk action is described like this:

```
type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<ReturnType, StateType, unknown, Action<string>>;
export const thunkAction = (id: number): AppThunk<Promise<{ status: string }>> => async (dispatch) => { ...do something, return correct type };
```

I've created type for my thunk-dispatch

```
export type AppThunkDispatch = ThunkDispatch<StateType, unknown, Action<string>>;
```

And after that I was able to use the return value without type errors, like this:

```
const data  = await (dispatch as AppThunkDispatch)(thunkAction(33));
if (data.status === 'success') { console.log('perfect') }
```

If you have only thunk actions to dispatch in this particular component, think you can define dispatch type once

```
const dispatch: AppThunkDispatch = useDispatch();
```

and avoid `(dispatch as AppThunkDispatch)` casting

Answer (score 0):

Here is my custom type:

```
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<ReturnType, RootState, unknown, Action<string>>
export function createThunk<T>(thunk: AppThunk<T>): T { return thunk as any };
```

Then, use it like the following:

```
export const getElementRefById = (elementId: string) => createThunk(async (dispatch, getState): Promise<ElementRef> => {
...actions
return data;
}
```

The return type for the above method will be the `Promise<ElementRef>` type.